# HTML nav bar will not touch the top of the page

Tags: html, css

I have been working on making a horizontal navigation bar for my site, but the top of the nav bar seems to be cut off and will not touch the top of the page.

I have tried using:

```
* { 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

However, that causes me to have to add padding to everything.

Is there any other way to fix it?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bp2jnytc/

Comment: Your css is doing exactly what you are telling it to do. I think you want to have some padding on your li elements. I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do but maybe this will help https://jsfiddle.net/happymacarts/5v9b4xwc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `<h3>` elements within your unordered lists, you could try:

```
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

And then for your `<ul>` element within your `<header>`:

```
header ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: How would you remove the little bit of space on the left and right of them?

Comment: For your `body` styles, instead of `margin-top: 0;`, it should be `margin: 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with it, well, at least when I copied the code to my text editor and then ran it in chrome. I believe it to be a problem with how jsfiddle is displaying the information, not to do with your code.

Answer (score -1):

Remove margin-top from the `ul` and the `h3` tag.  https://jsfiddle.net/bp2jnytc/2/

Comment: no, i need those for other parts of my website.

Comment: So style them independently for your nav! That's the whole point of having CSS.

Comment: tried that. doesn't work.

Comment: Of course it does. I just took your code and made it work in that fiddle.

Comment: I don't see a difference between my fiddle and yours...

Comment: Really? https://jsfiddle.net/bp2jnytc/3/ Oh the previous one is a copy of yours.